# Is this statement about improper integral True? Am I right?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, continuity, improper-integrals

1. "If $g(x)$ is a positive continuous function on $(0,1)$ and $\int_0^1 g(x) \, dx$ converges. Then $\int_0^1 \sqrt{g(x)}$ also converges."
2. "If $f(x) \ge 0$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converges, Then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$"

Because of $\sqrt{g(x)}\ge {g(x)}$ for $0 \le g(x) \le 1$ , I think statement "1" is false.

And I think statement "2" is true.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\sqrt{g}$ is bounded above by $\max\{g,1\}$, whose improper integral exists finitely, as you would observe. In fact, speaking more generally, using monotone convergence theorem it can be shown that such a non-negative function must be Lebesgue integrable, and this integral must coincide with the improper Riemann integral. You can, if you please, show that for a finite measure space $(X,B,\mu)$, we always have $L^2(X)\subset L^1(X)$. Kindly ignore this in case you haven't done measure theory yet. And you haven't clearly written the second part of your question, so I would take it that you mean whether or not convergence of the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f$ implies the limit of $f$ is zero as $x\rightarrow\infty$. This is false,because you must realize, while integrating you are essentially computing an area, so modifications of a function on sufficiently "small" sets(like the countable ones, if you please) does not change the value of the integral. With this in mind, you may define $f$ as $f(n)=n$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, and zero elsewhere. This should suffice for a counterexample.

Comment: I edit second part. Is it True? Also, you mean the 1st statement is False right?..

Comment: The second statement is false,as I have explained above.The first one happens to be true.You have rightly noted that whenever $g(x)\leq 1$, $\sqrt{g(x)}\geq g(x)$,however,you must also observe that in that case,$\sqrt{g(x)}$ is also less or equal to $1$.So here,it's bounded above by $1$,it's growth is stunted,and elsewhere,it's bounded above by $g$ itself,which happens to have finite improper integral.You can guess the net effect now.

Comment: Oh... Thank you for your effort!!!

Comment: You clearly don't know how punctuation is done in English or in European languages generally. See my edits to this answer. They way you wrote it will look very strange to any native user of any European language.